# how to see who has logged into apache http proxy server

Tags: apache, proxy, http-proxy

is there a way to find out who (based on username and password that I configured in the server) is connected to and is using apache proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out!
the line *#LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.dll* is the answer that I removed *#* sign from that!